# JS - Check if Array inside of an Object is empty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I loop over and check if one or some arrays inside of a JavaScript Object is empty?

i.e.

```
const store = {
shirts : [],
shoes: ['nike', 'puma', 'addidas']
hats: [],
jerseys: ['barcelona', 'milan', 'arsenal']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the values of the object using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). Check if at least one of them is an array with the `length` of 0 using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```js
const store = {
  shirts: [],
  shoes: ['nike', 'puma', 'addidas'],
  hats: [],
  jerseys: ['barcelona', 'milan', 'arsenal']
}

console.log(
  Object.values(store).some(v => Array.isArray(v) && v.length === 0)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know whether there is an empty array, val will be true if one of the arrays is empty, otherwise false.

```
val = Object.keys(store).some(key => store[key].length === 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const store = {
shirts : [],
shoes: ['nike', 'puma', 'addidas'],
hats: [],
jerseys: ['barcelona', 'milan', 'arsenal']
}

for(let item in store){
  if(store[item].length == 0)
    console.log(item)
}
```

---

Each empty item will be logged to console

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner:

```js
const main = o => Object.entries(o).some(([k,a])=>!a.length);

console.log(
  main({x: [1,2,3],y: [123],}), // false
  main({x: [1,2,3],y: [],}), // true
  main({x: [],y: [],}), // true
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the empty keys than you can use filter method

```
const store = {
  shirts : [],
  shoes: ['nike', 'puma', 'addidas'],
  hats: [],
  jerseys: ['barcelona', 'milan', 'arsenal']
}

const emptyKeys = Object.keys(store).filter((key) => {
                     if (store[key].length == 0) { 
                       return key; 
                     } 
                   });

console.log(emptyKeys);
```